# Efficiently determining whether or not two collections have any items in common in Java

Tags: java, collections, set, intersection

I know that, in Java, I can manually determine if two collections have any overlap by turning one of them into a set then iterating over the other doing contains checks:

```
<T> boolean anyInCommon(Iterable<T> collection1, Set<T> collection2) {
    for (T item : collection1)
        if (collection2.contains(item))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
<T> boolean anyInCommon(Iterable<T> collection1, Set<T> collection2) {
    return collection1.stream().anyMatch(collection2::contains);
}
```

But are there existing utility methods that do this and intelligently choose which collection to iterate, which to turn into a set, take advantage of one already being a set, etc? I know that Guava has `Sets.intersection`, but it computes the *entire* intersection instead of just whether or not it's empty.

Note that I'd prefer the comparison to short-circuit as soon as any common item is found. Checking if two huge collections have overlap should take time proportional to the number of non-overlapping items (or better), instead of the total number of items.

Comment: Not answering your question, but if the goal is just to find whether there is any intersection, then I suspect in many cases it may be a waste of time to do the conversion to set. It does depend on how many duplicates you have, of course.

Comment: Does it only depends on the number of duplicates ? I think the most important difference is the cost of the `contains` test, which is expected to be better in a `Set` than in any other kind of `Collection`.

Comment: Also if the .contains() used is of a `HashSet` the amortized time is O(1) thus giving you a O(n) Intersection method

Comment: @cornuz If the collections are small that's true, but for large collections improving the `m` queries to each take `O(1)` time instead of `O(n)` time is absolutely worth it because you go from `O(n*m)` to `O(n+m)`. Short-circuiting lets you do even better when there's a lot of overlap.

Comment: Yes I agree completely

Comment: Set and Iterable cannot be used interchangably so there solution provided is the most efficient.

Comment: When you have large collections you can usually redesign your application so it is not doing full brute force comparisons. e.g. you can make it event driven and check whether adding one entry, or changing one entry alters whether there was a match.  In a more realistic example you would avoid doing this in the first place.

Comment: If the sets are hash sets, the time complexity will be O(N), and if they have short circuit, they will be O(N/x) which is still O(N) though often faster (as the factor is lower), the complexity is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer for when the collections are already Sets.

`Sets.intersection` is actually closer to what I wanted than I thought because its result is not precomputed. Instead, [it's a *view*](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection&#40java.util.Set, java.util.Set&#41) of the intersection that's computed on the fly.

Take a look at [the anonymous class returned by `intersection`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-gwt/src-super/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#602):

```
final Predicate<Object> inSet2 = Predicates.in(set2);
return new SetView<E>() {
  @Override public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return Iterators.filter(set1.iterator(), inSet2);
  }
  @Override public int size() {
    return Iterators.size(iterator());
  }
  @Override public boolean isEmpty() {
    return !iterator().hasNext();
  }
  @Override public boolean contains(Object object) {
    return set1.contains(object) && set2.contains(object);
  }
  @Override public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
    return set1.containsAll(collection)
        && set2.containsAll(collection);
  }
};
```

The `isEmpty` method doesn't go over every item. Instead, it iterates over the first set while checking if items are in the second set. As soon as it finds one, it returns true. If you're unlucky you'll iterate all the items in set1 that aren't in set2 first, but that's probably unavoidable and better than always iterating all items.

In other words, *if you already have sets*, an efficient solution that short-circuits appropriately is just:

```
boolean overlaps = !Sets.intersections(set1, set2).isEmpty();
```

This won't iterate over the smaller set instead of the larger set, or deal with non-set collections, but it's often useful.

Comment: Using an intersection can be orders of magnitude slower than stopping after find the first match.  Building a new set is much more expensive than just counting the number of matches which is much more expensive than stopping after the first one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, that's why this answer is explaining and showing that `Sets.intersection.isEmpty` stops after the first match and doesn't build an entire new set.

Comment: Never the less, it must create an object to call `isEmpty` on so this is going to be slower than a method which works the same way, but doesn't create an object.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but the body of the question is asking for existing methods that already do the job at least somewhat efficiently. This is the closest one I've found.